Frozen laptop: Is there a way to maintain the current state of the OS after rebooting if it's a live USB?
I've been using a live Ubuntu USB (try-mode) because I just needed it temporarily to download and move some files.
However, the laptop I'm using is relatively old, and it can sometimes freeze up. I wouldn't want to lose the files I saved within the user folders, but I'm aware that live boots don't save anything.

The live environment is a COW system that is intended for testing the hardware, fixing minor issues & deciding if you want to install the system. If you use it as if it's an installed system, the system will become slow and can eventually became unstable as you're using it beyond what the COW (copy on write) was intended for; the fix is to install and use the system as intended. You don't provide any specifics as to what Ubuntu product, what release/ISO you're asking about though; but COW writes the system to RAM which gets lost on reboot.
